# google maps in java blackberry plug in

Tags: google-maps, blackberry, java-me

I want to use google maps in my application, Blackberry Java plug-in project. Which libraries I can use and is there any source code for this example?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I would love to be wrong here, but I have found that there is no library for Google Maps on blackberry.  You have three options:

1. [Send some data to the Google Maps app](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Invoking-google-maps-opens-currenlty-active-instance-of-google/td-p/1068353) and then have it launch/run on its own.
2. Sign up for a [Google Maps Premier](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html) account and use the [Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).
3. Completely roll your own (I'm guessing this may need a Google Maps Premier account as well).